# Use reduceByKeyAndWindow in Spark Streaming on multiple values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

have a question on the reduceByKeyAndWindow function in Spark Streaming. This might be naive, am new-ish to both Scala and Spark.

After parsing my data I have this data set with three columns: 
  Column 1: Key, 
  Column 2: Amount (Long), 
  Column 3: Count (Long)

Is there a way to run this through the reduceByKeyAndWindow function and get the sum of both Column 2 (Amount) and Column 3 (Count) over a specified window?

From what I have read, looks like the reduceByKeyAndWindow function expects only two columns (key, value), so what I am currently doing is creating two data sets:
   **Data set 1**: key, Amount && 
   **Data set 2**: key, Count

And then, I am calling the reduceByKeyAndWindow twice. Would be great if I could just do it once (the parameters to reduce are same of both the amount and count columns)

Does this question make sense? Any inputs would be awesome!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it easily . You have to map to (key,(v1,v2)) and then use a simple function as below to reduceByKeyAndWindow.

```
val data = Array(("key1",(1L,2L)),("key1",(9L,1L)),("key2",(1L,2L)),("key2",(99L,11L)))

val rdd = sc.parallelize(k)

val aggregateFunc: ((Long, Long), (Long, Long)) => (Long, Long) = {
      case ((v1, w1), (v2, w2)) => {
         (v1 + v2, w1 + w2)
       }
    }
rdd.reduceByKey(aggregateFunc).collect()
// Array((key1,(10,3)), (key2,(100,13)))
```

The above function will work for reduceByKeyAndWindow

Comment: Thx Knight71! This worked just fine. Created two functions, one to add and one to subtract (for batches that fall outside the window). And then it was easy enough to add the functions in the reduceByKeyAndWindow:  reduceByKeyAndWindow(aggregateFuncAdd, aggregateFuncSubtract, Minutes(windowLength.toLong), Seconds(slideInterval.toLong), 2)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am going out of scope here, but here is what I did for a case similar to yours. Java Pseudocode:

```
//inside your pipeline
private class AmountCountClass{
    private int amount;
    private int count;
    public AmountCountClass(int i,int j){
        amount=i;
        count=j;
    //various methods: get-set, increase-decrease,whatever you need
}
JavaPairDStream<Key,AmountCountClass> pairedAndReducedByKey= yourDStream.mapToPair( {
    return new Tuple2<yourKey, new AmountCountClass(initialAmount,initialCount);
}).reduceByKeyAndWindow(windowTime,windowSlide, 
    reduceFunction(AmountCountClass arg0, arg1){ 
        arg0.sumAmount(arg1.getAmount());
        arg0.sumCount(arg1.getCount());
        return arg0;
});
```

Very clean and readable.